# Why is my React DND implementation not working in Next JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I have this React DND implementation. There are multiple drop targets. I am able to drag the elements but it isn't being received by the targets. I tried doing console.log in the drop function of useDrop. There is nothing logging in console on drop. What might be the issue?

**DND provider implementation**

```
<DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend} debugMode>
              <TODOSection
                title={"TODOS"}
                todos={normalTodos}
                markCompleted={markCompleted}
                markProgress={markProgress}
              >
                {createTodoFormActive ? (
                  <form
                    className={styles.createTodoForm}
                    onSubmit={handleAddTodoFormSubmit}
                  >
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className={styles.createTodoInput}
                      placeholder="Enter TODO here..."
                      value={todoInputText}
                      required
                      onChange={(event) => setTodoInputText(event.target.value)}
                    />
                    <button type="submit" className={styles.todoSubmitBtn}>
                      Add
                    </button>
                  </form>
                ) : (
                  <button
                    className={styles.addTodoBtn}
                    onClick={() => setCreateTodoFormActive(true)}
                  >
                    <Icon icon={"carbon:add"} /> Add todos
                  </button>
                )}
              </TODOSection>

              <TODOSection
                title="IN PROGRESS"
                todos={progressTodos}
                markCompleted={markCompleted}
                markProgress={markProgress}
              />
              <TODOSection
                title="COMPLETED"
                todos={completedTodos}
                markCompleted={markCompleted}
                markProgress={markProgress}
              />
            </DndProvider>
```

**Draggable component using useDrag hook**

```
const TODOItem = ({
  children,
  markCompleted,
  markProgress,
  todoId,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  markCompleted: Function;
  markProgress: Function;
  todoId: string;
}) => {
  const [{ opacity, isDragging, didDrop, dropResult, targetIds }, dragRef] =
    useDrag(() => ({
      type: "todoItem",
      // item: { children },
      item: { id: todoId },
      collect: (monitor) => ({
        opacity: monitor.isDragging() ? 0.5 : 1,
        isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
        didDrop: monitor.didDrop(),
        dropResult: monitor.getDropResult(),
        targetIds: monitor.getTargetIds(),
      }),
    }));

  const handleDrop = (id: string, monitor: any) => {
    markCompleted(id);
    console.log(monitor);
  };

  console.log(dropResult, targetIds);
  return (
    <div className={styles.todoItem} ref={dragRef} style={{ opacity }}>
      <p className={styles.todoText}>{children}</p>
      <div className={styles.todoActions}>
        <button
          className={`${styles.todoActionBtn} ${styles.markPending}`}
          title="Mark as In Progress"
          onClick={() => markProgress(todoId)}
        >
          <Icon icon={"bx:time-five"} />
        </button>
        <button
          className={`${styles.todoActionBtn} ${styles.markCompleted}`}
          title="Mark as Completed"
          onClick={() => markCompleted(todoId)}
        >
          <Icon icon={"charm:circle-tick"} />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Drop Target component**

```
const TODOSection = ({
  todos,
  children,
  markCompleted,
  markProgress,
  title,
}: {
  todos: ITodoItem[];
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  markCompleted: Function;
  markProgress: Function;
  title?: string;
}) => {
  const [{ isOver, canDrop, item }, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
    accept: "todoItem",
    drop: (item) => {
      console.log(item, "dropped");
    },

    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isOver: monitor.isOver(),
      canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
      item: monitor.getItem(),
    }),
  }));

  console.log(isOver, canDrop, item);

  return (
    <div className={styles.todoSection} ref={drop}>
      <h3 className={styles.todoSectionTitle}>{title}</h3>
      {todos.length > 0 ? (
        todos.map((todo) => (
          <TODOItem
            markCompleted={markCompleted}
            markProgress={markProgress}
            todoId={todo.id}
          >
            {todo.text}
          </TODOItem>
        ))
      ) : (
        <p className={styles.nothingHere}>Nothing here</p>
      )}
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The React DND package didn't work. So, I used another package called [@dnd-kit](https://dndkit.com)

The implementation was so easy and everything is working just fine. You can use it if you are looking for a DND package to use with React/Next JS.

Comment: Good advice, recommended repo, maintained and powerful. Examples of my (working) first attempts also in my open-source DAW repo: https://github.com/artiphishle/daw

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the `DndProvider` and `HTML5Backend` with dynamic import. Fixed for me.

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const DndProvider = dynamic(
  () => import("react-dnd").then((dnd) => dnd.DndProvider),
  { ssr: false }
);
const HTML5Backend: any = dynamic(
  () =>
    import('react-dnd-html5-backend').then((html) => html.HTML5Backend as any),
  { ssr: false }
);
```